# How do I set a background for a primeNg Tree control

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

Angular CLI 6
primeNg 6.0.1

I am trying to change the background for the tree component to no avail.
when I use, in the html file, style="background:red" the tree becomes confused and gets a height of one.
Similar behavior when I use styleClass.

Has anyone had any luck with setting the tree background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just using the style property wrongly, you should enter your CSS in json format like this (expects an object):

```
[style]="{'background':'red'}"
```

You can also use the styleClass property to avoid inline styles as much as you can, though probably the background color is already set in one of the classes applied to the tree component